# How to make LruCache only accept key?

Tags: android, android-lru-cache

`LruCache` is a map, but I want to use `LruCache` to only cache strings, i.e. I want LruCache to work as a HashSet.

How should I define a `LruCache` class?

`LruCache<String, Void>` won't work, because when my code called `lruCache.put("abc", null)`, `NullPointerException` was thrown.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't store `null`. Store something else, such as a `String`.

Comment: OK. I think I have to define LruCache<String, String>, and put the string as both key and value, e.g lruCache.put(stringToCache, StringToCache).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) are pretty clear:

> This class does not allow null to be used as a key or value. A return value of null from `get(K)`, `put(K, V)` or `remove(K)` is unambiguous: the key was not in the cache.

You can define your own string wrapper class to use for values. You can have a special instance of it to represent null strings.

```
public class StringValue {
    public final String string;
    public StringValue(String s) {
        string = s;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(string); // in case it's null
    }
    public String asString() {
        return string;
    }
    public static final StringValue NULL = new StringValue(null);
}
```

Then you can store a non-null null:

```
LruCache<String, StringValue> lruCache = new LruCache<String, StringValue>();
lruCache.put("abc", StringValue.NULL);
lruCache.put("def", new StringValue("something"));
```